# Upgrading to ToadForMySQL version 7.2.0.2922 and now have authentication issue

Tags: mysql, toad

I am new to TOAD.

I upgraded my ToadForMySQL client on my Windows 7 box from ToadForMySQL 7.0.0.2038 to ToadForMySQL 7.2.0.2922.  I have 4 databases that I currently connect to.  Of the 4 connection entries that I have in my Connection Manager I can only connect to 3.  When I try to connect to the 4th database using my connection entry I get this error:

> MySQL Database Error
>
> Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.  Nothing has changed regarding permissions or passwords in any of these connections.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the REPLICATION CONFIG whereby our DBA has not yet converted users to use the 4.1 style passwords. Just in case someone else had the same issue I thought I'd better post my findings.  Thanks.